# System.FormatException: Index (Zero Based} Error

Tags: c#

I am getting this error with this one line. I dont know what the issue is. I have searched google and it says you get this error when you dont put a 0 for your write variable in your writeline but i didnt do that. The line that gives me the error is 2nd one from the bottom. Heres my code

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
class TemperaturesComparison
{
   static void Main()
   {
      
      
      double Temp1;
      double Temp2;
      double Temp3;
      double Temp4;
      double Temp5;
      string response;

      
      WriteLine ("Enter 5 Temps");

      response = ReadLine ();
      Temp1 = Convert.ToDouble(response);
      response = ReadLine ();
      Temp2 = Convert.ToDouble(response);
      response = ReadLine ();
      Temp3 = Convert.ToDouble(response);
      response = ReadLine ();
      Temp4 = Convert.ToDouble(response);
      response = ReadLine ();
      Temp5 = Convert.ToDouble(response);

      if (Temp5> Temp4 && Temp4> Temp3 && Temp3> Temp2 && Temp2> Temp1 )

      {
        WriteLine ("Getting Warmer");
      }

      if (Temp5< Temp4 && Temp4< Temp3 && Temp3< Temp2 && Temp2< Temp1)

      {
        WriteLine ("Getting cooler");
      }

  double addup;
  double average;

  addup = Temp1+Temp2+Temp3+Temp4+Temp5;
  average = addup/5;

  WriteLine ("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5}",Temp1,Temp2,Temp3,Temp4,Temp5);
  WriteLine ("Average : {0}", average);


  
   

   }
}
```

Comment: The line has 6 place holders, but you only 5 values. Put one more value in and it should be fine

Comment: Or, you should remove the last place holder, if you only want to output 5 values

Answer (score 1):

Writeline has note same the numbers of placeholder and assigned values change your code such as
WriteLine ("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}",Temp1,Temp2,Temp3,Temp4,Temp5)